# SAS max date with other variables

Tags: sql, sas, max

I'm having issues trying to take the most recent manager name on this data set, posted below, how would i do this in `PROC SQL`?

I keep doing the max of lSTDATE, however it is still duplicating the Acct_Number with i keep in the manager name? Thoughts?

```
NAME       Manager  ACCT_NUMBER    LSTDATE
ABC CORP    GBARRY  12345-54321    2015-12-03 12:53:55.000
ABC CORP    THONER  12345-54321    2015-12-16 20:42:00.000
TEST 1      YWONG   56561-67843    2014-02-16 20:02:00.000
TEST 3      KSMITH  90010-55531    2014-04-19 20:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your query.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*
    from t
    where t.lstdate = (select max(t2.lstdate)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.acct_number = t.acct_number
                      );
```